# Fighting Flashes of Unstyled Text in Single Page Apps in vue

Tags: css, performance, vue.js, fonts

FOUT in SPAs using FEFs. That's a lot of odd acronyms. :)

But it's still an issue.

I have a dynamic component which loads a bunch of components which are meant to look in a very specific way. Each would have its own css, and critically, its own specific fonts.

The fonts are the issue here.

**What ways are there to avoid this FOUT in this case?**

This is my current research on the topic:

1. Browsers have a mechanism to hide text it detects is styled with a custom font until the font has loaded.

   - This does not work in vue, because the text isn't loaded yet either for the browser to detect, so when JS puts the text, this browser mechanism isn't triggered.
   - Might be fixable via SSR, static DOM - browser can now detect. Still might not want - FOIT (Flash of invisible text) arguably worse (no content vs bad content).
2. This does nothing for dynamic components

   - CSS is consolidated unless async component.
   - You do get all CSS imports, but not all fonts until they are used on the page. I.e. it makes a network request for the css import, but not the fonts, until something on the page gets styled with this font. At least it's... quic. :D
3. WebFontLoader?

   - A js library by google/typekit, companion to google web fonts.
   - Possibly can be used to delay component loading until the font has loaded using its events?
   - Requires things outside the component to know about the font.

     - No obvious way to reach down and pull out CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many fonts you're loading and the size there are a few things you could do.

1. Call the fonts in the base HTML file (separate from your other CSS) so the browser is aware of them. Then create a hidden div in the parent component with CSS calling the font for the child. This will cause the browser to request the font before the child component is loaded.
2. Load all fonts separately in the HTML with `rel='preload'` or `rel='prefetch'`. I would do this at the bottom of the HTML so you don't block other content.
3. Load your fonts in the `created` lifecycle hook using the [CSS Font Loading API](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-font-loading/). I'm not sure how this will work with Google Fonts vs self-hosting.
4. Create CSS transitions when loading content like a half-second fade to mask the FOUT. This is obviously not a solution but never underestimate the power of smoke and mirrors to influence the way your app feels.

Also, you should try to make use of the `font-display` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display)) CSS property. This won't solve the problem but it will make the results more predictable.

Comment: Excellent, this was precisely the cause I was struggling with! Thank you. Added usage of the font before my Vue code, and it worked perfectly. It also worked fine just removing the swap=true from the google font request. I found this page having a good breakdown https://css-tricks.com/the-best-font-loading-strategies-and-how-to-execute-them/